# Least norm problem for any norm?

Tags: analysis, least-squares

Now I have questions about the following variants of least square problem

If $A$ is a $ m \times n$ matrix(which need not be full rank, but can assume $m \geq n$) and let $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Also assume $|| . ||$ be an arbitrary norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that there is a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ ||Ax -b||$ is minimized.

If $||.||$ is given by standard 2-norms, then it becomes least square problem. Can we assure the existence of such vectors for arbitrary norms?

I tried to use compact argument for continuity of the quantity we want to minimize, but boundedness of domain always bothers me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace $A$ with a matrix that has orthogonal columns of length $1$. Then, because all norms are equivalent, you get that the length of $Ax$ under your norm is greater than $C||x||_2$ for some fixed constant $C > 0$. Thus, if $||x||_2$ is too large then $Ax$ will be far away from $b$. So you can assume you are minimizing your function over a compact domain, so a minimum exists.

Comment: It is true for any norm(even if the norm is not operator norm) is equivalent? And why the first assumption makes sense?

Comment: @Detectives Every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space is equivalent up to constant bounding factors. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Properties . As for the first assumption, for any choice of $A$ the set of $Ax$ is equal to the span of the columns of $A$, which is a subspace, and every subspace has an orthonormal basis where every basis vector has length 1 and all pairs of basis vectors are orthogonal. This just makes the reasoning a little easier to make because the bounding set for $x$ might look a bit weird for arbitrary $A$.